# SingularValueDecomposition outputs unsolved Root expressions

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I have a simple 4x10 matrix of real integers (It's a Vandermonde matrix for x=1,2,...,10, if that's relevant) that I'm trying to do SVU decomposition on.  When I use the SingularValueDecomposition command, the result is a huge mess of roots:

Code:

```
A = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 4, 8}, {1, 3, 9, 27}, {1, 4, 16, 64}, {1, 5,
     25, 125}, {1, 6, 36, 216}, {1, 7, 49, 343}, {1, 8, 64, 512}, {1, 
    9, 81, 729}, {1, 10, 100, 1000}};
{U, S, V} = SingularValueDecomposition[A];
Print[U]
Print[S]
```

Output snippet:

```
{{(1-(12231648+1703130 Root[1345481280-8036854848 #1+1486520211 #1^2-2004133 #1^3+#1^4&,4]-7 Root[1345481280-8036854848 #1+1486520211 #1^2-2004133 #1^3+#1^4&,4]^2)/(11 (61776+14238 Root[1345481280-8036854848 #1+1486520211 #1^2-2004133 #1^3+#1^4&,4]+5 Root[1345481280-8036854848 #1+1486520211 #1^2-2004133 #1^3+#1^4&,4]^2))-(-64555920+589248 Root[1345481280-8036854848 #1+1486520211 #1^2-2004133 #1^3+#1^4&,4]-Root[1345481280-8036854848 #1+1486520211 #1^2-2004133 #1^3+#1^4&,4]^2)/(11 (61776+14238 Root[1345481280-8036854848 #1+1486520211 #1^2-2004133 #1^3+#1^4&,4]+5 Root[1345481280-8036854848 #1+1486520211 #1^2-2004133 #1^3+#1^4&,4]^2))-(5067979488-1475780856 Root[1345481280-8036854848 #1+1486520211 #1^2-2004133 #1^3+#1^4&,4]+2004123 Root[1345481280-8036854848 #1+1486520211 #1^2-2004133 #1^3+#1^4&,4]^2-Root[1345481280-8036854848 #1+1486520211 #1^2-2004133 #1^3+#1^4&,4]^3)/(605 (61776+14238 Root[1345481280-8036854848 #1+1486520211 #1^2-2004133 #1^3+#1^4&,4]+5 Root[1345481280-8036854848 #1+1486520211 #1^2-2004133 #1^3+#1^4&,4]^2)))/(\[Sqrt]((1000-(100 (12231648+1703130 Root[1345481280-8036854848 #1+
```

And so on, and so on...

How can I force it to evaluate these roots?

Comment: Do this A={{...},...}//N and then you can the numerical values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this.

```
A = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 4, 8}, {1, 3, 9, 27}, {1, 4, 16, 64}, {1, 5,
      25, 125}, {1, 6, 36, 216}, {1, 7, 49, 343}, {1, 8, 64, 512}, {1,
      9, 81, 729}, {1, 10, 100, 1000}} // N;
{U, S, V} = SingularValueDecomposition[A];
U // MatrixForm
S // MatrixForm
```

You can confirm the results.

```
U.S.Conjugate[Transpose[V]] // Rationalize
```

> {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 4, 8}, {1, 3, 9, 27}, {1, 4, 16, 64}, {1, 5, 25,
>      125}, {1, 6, 36, 216}, {1, 7, 49, 343}, {1, 8, 64, 512}, {1, 9, 81,
>      729}, {1, 10, 100, 1000}}

Comment: Yep! That was it.  Thank you very much, Junho.  I see that I just was forcing the numbers to be numeric at the wrong place.  Or at least, that's how I interpret this.

Comment: @FrankHarris: "I just was forcing the numbers to be numeric at the wrong place." Yup, you've got it right. If you give `SingularValueDecomposition` (or many other symbolic methods) integer input, it will give horrifyingly large exact symbolic expressions, which you can apply `N` to to get numeric results. But if numerical results are what you are after, then it is more efficient and safer to apply `N` to your initial matrix first, and *then* apply the SVD.

Answer (score 10):

This is not a matter of "force". A `Root` object represents the exact root of a polynomial that cannot be represented exactly in closed form, or (in the case of cubics and quartics) cannot be represented succinctly. It is not "unsolved"; it is just a way of writing something that is hard or impossible to write down otherwise.

If you want to convert cubic or quartic `Root` objects to radicals, use `ToRadicals`:

```
Root[1345481280 - 8036854848 #1 + 1486520211 #1^2 - 2004133 #1^3 + #1^4 &,
  4
 ] // ToRadicals
(* -> 2004133/4 + 
 Sqrt[4012585027793/4 + 21832541169757571/(88409040345503470315691 + 
  (120*I)*Sqrt[176821665157935758420883814538881436163])^(1/3) + 
  11*(88409040345503470315691 +
  (120*I)*Sqrt[176821665157935758420883814538881436163])^(1/3)]/2 + 
 Sqrt[4012585027793/2 - 21832541169757571/(88409040345503470315691 + 
  (120*I)*Sqrt[176821665157935758420883814538881436163])^(1/3) - 
  11*(88409040345503470315691 +
  (120*I)*Sqrt[176821665157935758420883814538881436163])^(1/3) + 
 8037781888187331169/(4*
  Sqrt[4012585027793/4 + 21832541169757571/(88409040345503470315691 +
   (120*I)*Sqrt[176821665157935758420883814538881436163])^(1/3) + 
   11*(88409040345503470315691 +
   (120*I)*Sqrt[176821665157935758420883814538881436163])^(1/3)])]/2 *)
```

This is easily found in [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ToRadicals.html).

Answer (score 6):

Let me reconstruct your Vandermonde matrix:

```
A = Outer[Power, Range[10], Range[0, 3]];
A // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Then there are two possibilities to compute SVD:

1. Analytic expressions
2. Numerical values

Your input is the integer array so *Mathematica* choose the first one and try to give your the answer in an analytic form. It returns the result as roots of the polynomials. The degree of the polynomials is 4 so you can force to give an explicit result

```
{U, S, V} = SingularValueDecomposition[A, Quartics -> True];
U
```

[image]

Unfortunately options `Quartics -> True` and `Cubics -> True` are not documented for SVD, but they work as in `Eigenvalues`. But formulas are very huge! I'm not sure that it is what you want.

To choose the numerical computations you should convert your array to the numerical array

```
{U, S, V} = SingularValueDecomposition[N[A]];
V // MatrixForm
```

[image]